# Change variable dynamically SCSS

Tags: html, css, web, sass

I am new at SCSS. I want to override a variable dynamically. The condition if the value will be set, depends if the draggable attribute is on the div element. If the draggable attribute is set on the div, the variable get an value. If not the value has to be empty.

```html
<body>

<div class="notice" draggable="true">
    <h1>Text</h1>
        <p>More text</p>
</div>
```

```css
/* global variable */
$draggable: url('') !default;

/* my "abstract" class */
body{
    &[draggable="true"]{
        $draggable: url('../icons/IDlink.png');
        /* here is $draggable: '../icons/IDlink.png' */
        @debug "$draggable in body is #{$draggable}"; 
    }
}

div{
    @extend body;
    &[class="notice"]{
        @debug "$draggableChain in safetyadvice is #{$draggableChain}";
        /* here is $draggable: empty */
        @include backgroundTest(url('../icons/notice_ISO.png'), url('../icons/notice_BG.png'), $draggable);
    }
```

I have create a global variable $draggable with a empty url-property. Next I have a "abstract class" body. In this "class" I want to override the $draggable variable. This seems to work, cuz the debug get the right value back. In the div "class" which extends from the body is the $draggable variable empty again. Why is it? What do I wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks for help

Comment: You do understand that Sass is compiled to CSS, right?  It never gets sent to the browser, there is no way for it to know anything about the DOM.

Comment: Sure. I want to get the value, which is set to $draggable in the body-element and use it in the div, but there is the $draggable value empty. This has nothing to do with DOM. I am thinking that the $draggable variable in body do not reference to the global one.